# How to change the text color of button on hover anywhere on the button, not just the text?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to create a simple button where both the background color and text color changes color on hover. Background color I got but text color only change color when I hover directly on the text. [I have a CodePen on this for an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbQQre) and here's the code I used:

```css
button {
    background: #4e368f;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    border: 0;;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
button:hover { background: #5e4999; }
button.go-now { width: 100%; }
button.go-now a { color: #ccc; text-decoration: none; }
button.go-now a:hover { color: #fff; }
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="go-now">
        <a href="#" title="Go" target="_blank">Go Now</a>
   </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Buttons should not contain links....it's invalid HTML. Pick one or the other.

Comment: https://karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
        button {
        background: #4e368f;
        color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        margin-top: 0;
        border: 0;;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
    button:hover { background: #5e4999; }
    button.go-now { width: 100%; }
    button.go-now a { color: #ccc; text-decoration: none; }
    button.go-now a:hover { color: #fff; }
    button:hover .test{
 color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
    <p style="text-align: center;"><button class="go-now"><a href="#" title="Go to Armis Console" class="test" target="_blank">Go Now</a></button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close you just need to change the color of the text when your button is hovered over. Right now you have the anchor tag changing to white when it is being hovered over.

```
button:hover .go-now a { color: #fff; }
```